# Running application in Visual studio v k web

Tags: asp.net-core

When I F5 an application in VS2014 it runs on IIS Express on some random port e.g.
49346

When I run with K web, there is no IIS Express. What is hosting the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs the web command as defined in your project.json. The guide on the ASP site ( http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/getting-started-with-aspnet-vnext-and-visual-studio ) uses the following: `"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"`. Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener is not in the aspnet github repositories, but is included in their myGet feed. ( https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext )

Comment: thanks christiaanderidder. What is hosting this then?

Comment: It starts up Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting via a regular Main() method with the parameters that are listed above. As far as I can see both libraries are closed source. Ofcourse you could look into the DLL's with a tool like dotPeek to get a better understanding of how they work.